# Set a static IP on AWS Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, elastic-stack, amazon-elb

Here is my context : I'm trying to migrate a cluster from Digital Ocean to AWS (Eks).

I'm currently experiencing a problem with the external ip of my load balancer and I don't know how to reproduce the behavior of DO because I don't have a *real* external IP.

Here is a schema of our architecture :

[image: routing architecture]

In our cluster, we got a loadBalancer with an external IP.
We created a traefik that create link between our services and DNS.
Each DNS points to the external ip of the load balancer.

I want to reproduce this behavior on my eks cluster.

I created a loadBalancer with the following yaml

```yaml
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      name: web
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      name: dashboard
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      name: websecure
```

It worked well because I got an external ip : `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com` and if I go on `http://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com:8080`, my traefik dashboard is display !

But there is two problems :

- It's a DNS and not a IP, I tried to dig on the dns and ping the resulting IP but it doesn't worked...
- The DNS of my LB isn't constant, and that a real problem ? How the DNS can be link to my service ?

I've found many post on stack Overflow related but I didn't find my answers, and I'm not even sure that is possible because of **AWS scalability**.

Thank you. I hope someone can help me

Comment: "The DNS of my LB isn't constant" how did you determine that? It is definitely constant unless you are deleting and recreating the LB. If you are using an AWS ALB then you will need to use the DNS name instead of the IP. If you switch to an NLB then you will have a static IP.

Comment: I deleted the LB to test it yes, if I switch to an NLB I'll have a *real* external IP instead of a DNS ?

Comment: You can assign an AWS Elastic IP to a Network Load Balancer. It will have to be one per availability zone, so you will end up with 2 or 3 static IPs for the NLB. ALBs have a lot of nice features you will no longer have access to though. Generally it's better to go with ALB and use a CNAME in your DNS records instead of an A record.

Comment: I understand but what happend if something delete my loadBalancer ? All my CNAME will be obsolet ?

Let's imagine, I got an ALB DNS to `XXX-amazon.com`, then I should do CNAME as following :
 - `service-one.my-domain.com` -> `XXX-amazon.com`
 - `service-two.my-domain.com` -> `XXX-amazon.com`
 - `service-three.my-domain.com` -> `XXX-amazon.com`

What will hapend if the LB is dead ? I would like to find a way where I can redeploy everything on my cluster and it can still running perfectly.

Do you think it's possible ?

Comment: 1. You should enable deletion protection on your load balancer. 2. You should be using some sort of infrastructure-as-code that sets the CNAME record when the load balancer is created, so that it is always in-sync.

Comment: Okay thank you, I understand, I'll try to to do this with terraform